# Might be growing inside the loop. Consider Prealocating for Speed

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide, matlab-deployment

```
clear all
k_1 = 37.6;
miu_1 = 41;
Den = 2.7;
N = 100;
n=1;
phi(1)=1;
for n=1:N
phi(n)= 0.3*(n/N);
K_s(n)= K_1*(1-(1+(3*k_1)/(4*miu_1))*phi(n));
miu_s(n)= miu_1*(1-(1+(3*k_1)/(4*miu_1))*phi(n));
den1(n)=Den*(1-phi(n));
vp(n)=sqrt((k_s(n)+(4/3)*miu_s(n))/den1(n));
end
figure(1);
plot(phi,miu_s);
figure(2);
plot (phi,vp)
```

i am new on matlab and do not know what is problem with my code when i run my program only a beep buzz and nothing happens. guide me

Comment: The message in your title is just a warning, related to performance. If your code isn't working, then it's for some other reason.

Comment: thanks for comment but what can be the reason?? sir @Tom Fenech

Comment: Preallocation or the lack of, check out my answer

Comment: Please can you edit your question so that it is clearer. What are you trying to do? What isn't working?

Comment: "Beep buzz"? What is the problem: doesn't compile? Gives wrong answer?

Comment: Same person or classmate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22294980

Answer (score 2):

The reason your code doesn't work is case sensitivity. You are using k_1 and K_1, and k_s and K_s (unless that is intentional). When I change that, your code compiles ok.

```
clear all
k_1 = 37.6;
miu_1 = 41;
Den = 2.7;
N = 100;
n=1;
phi(1)=1;
for n=1:N
phi(n)= 0.3*(n/N);
k_s(n)= k_1*(1-(1+(3*k_1)/(4*miu_1))*phi(n));
miu_s(n)= miu_1*(1-(1+(3*k_1)/(4*miu_1))*phi(n));
den1(n)=Den*(1-phi(n));
vp(n)=sqrt((k_s(n)+(4/3)*miu_s(n))/den1(n));
end
figure(1);
plot(phi,miu_s);
figure(2);
plot (phi,vp)
```

Comment: i tried the same with case sensitive but did not worked in my case

Comment: My version of your code compiles ok for me. If you copy it exactly as is, it should work. Unless k_1 and K_1 are separate variables, but you haven't defined what K_1 is.

Answer (score 1):

when programming in MatLab, is usually a good practice to prealocate variables instead of declaring them in a loop. In this way, MatLab creates the object just once and changes each of it's values once in the loop. Otherwise you will be declaring a new variable and writing all its contents every loop iteration which is a costly process. Your Code might be working but be extreeeeemly slow, leading you to think nothing is happening. Try prealocating all the variables inside the loop with the `zeros()` function like this:

```
phi=zeros(N,1);
phi(1)=1;
K_s=zeros(N,1);
%... and so on for all your variables inside the loop

for n=1:N
phi(n)= 0.3*(n/N);
K_s(n)= k_1*(1-(1+(3*k_1)/(4*miu_1))*phi(n));
miu_s(n)= miu_1*(1-(1+(3*k_1)/(4*miu_1))*phi(n));
den1(n)=Den*(1-phi(n));
vp(n)=sqrt((k_s(n)+(4/3)*miu_s(n))/den1(n));
end
```

Hope that helps

Comment: You're right and doing this will prevent the warning but it shouldn't affect whether the code works or not.

Comment: The result will be the same, but it will greatly affect the speed! just try it!

Comment: Also take a look at @anderlucas remark on the case sensitivity ;)

Comment: It is correct as long as you declared 'N' somewhere above, it creates an array of size Nx1 and prealocates it with zeros.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing a lot of unnecessary things here, including that entire loop.

For example:

```
N = 100;
n=1; %this value is never used 
phi(1)=1; % this is overwritten in loop
for n=1:N
phi(n)= 0.3*(n/N);
... (loop continues)
```

You don't need a loop here. Instead, work on whole vectors

```
N = 100;
n = 1:100; %predefine vector
phi = 0.3*(n/N); % outputs vector of phi from 0.003 to 0.3
```

For cases when you are combining multiple vectors remember to use `./` and `.*` for element-wise divison and multiplication, e.g. the last equation will end up being:

```
vp=sqrt((k_s+(4/3)*miu_s)./den1);
```